# Change the whole UI on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, orientation, orientation-changes

I am currently developing a swift app and in one view I have to present a table (in the swift context) if the device is in portrait orientation and a grid (table in the excel/html context) if the orientation changes to landscape.

How can I achieve this behaviour in the UI given that I would need to go from a UITableView to a CollectionView?

Thank you very much.

From this:

[image: UItableView]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in Interface Builder by designing one view layout for size classes that are Compact horizontally, and another when they are Regular horizontally. You can also do vertical size class distinctions but for your case horizontal seems better.

Checkout Apple's documentation on using size classes to build different layouts:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Answer (score 0):

Override `UIView`'s method `(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator`.

In this method you need to check

```
If (size.width > size.height) {
//it is landscape, show collectionview
} else {
//its in portrait, show tableview
}
```